# How to find words which start with given letter

Tags: java, set, java-stream

Given string, for example: `My name is James Bond iee` I want to in result have `Map` with character as a key and set of strings as a value (this set of strings are strings starting with according character key) - `Map<Character,Set<String>>`.
For example:

`m - my, n - name, i - is, iee, j - james etc.`

I have done purifying string from punctuation marks and written method responsible for finding characters. In my example: `(m,n,u,j,b)`

These methods:

```
static String getPurifiedSentenceFromPunctuationMarks(String sentence) {
    return sentence.replaceAll("\\p{P}", "");
}

static Set<Character> getEveryCharacterOccuringInSentence(String sentence) {
    return sentence.chars()
                .mapToObj(e -> (char) e).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Now, I wanted to iterate through every character and every string to find these words, but I'm struggling with how to create set for every character:

```
String purifiedSentenceFromPunctuationMarks = AP.getPurifiedSentenceFromPunctuationMarks(sentence);
        Set<Character> characters = AP.getEveryCharacterOccuringInSentence(purifiedSentenceFromPunctuationMarks);
        String[] words = purifiedSentenceFromPunctuationMarks.split("\\s");
        Map<Character, Set<String>> characterWithAccordingWord = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        Set<String> nonRepeatableWords = new HashSet<>();

        for (char iteratedCharacter : characters) {
            for (String iteratedWord : words) {
                if (iteratedWord.indexOf(iteratedCharacter) >= 0) {
                    characterWithAccordingWord.put(iteratedCharacter, )
                }
            }
        }
```

As you see Ive stopped in the moment when string needs to be added to set for `iteratedCharacter`. How it can be done?
Maybe it is better with with streams? The most I would like to use streams here.

Answer (score 5):

Using streams, once you have an array of all the words in `String[] words`, you can group them by their first character and `collect` into a `Set` as :

```
Map<Character, Set<String>> characterWithAccordingWord =
        Arrays.stream(words).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(word -> word.charAt(0), 
                Collectors.toSet()));
```

Comment: Good answer ! Note that `word.toCharArray()[0]` allocates a new array. You want to use `word.charAt(0)` instead of.

Comment: @davidxxx Makes sense. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You have a `Map<Character, Set<String>>`

You have the letter 'n', and the word "name". And you want to make sure that the Set associated to that key 'n' in the map contains the word "name".

So what do you do? Well, you get the Set from the map, thanks to the key 'n'. And then you add the word to the Set.

What could go wrong? Well, there could be no Set in the map for the key 'n' yet. So, check if the set is null. If it's null, then create an empty set, and put it in the map, before adding the word to this new empty set.

You should try doing that by yourself, because it's fundamental to understand the basics of these collections.

Once that is done, you can use the Map's `computeIfAbsent()` method, which allows transforming the code into a one-liner.

And once that is done, then you can start looking into Streams, and use the `groupingBy` collector.

Answer (score 2):

To preserve the occurrence order of the words in the sentence along with the `Collectors.groupingBy()` you also need to mention that you need it in an `LinkedHashMap`:

```
 String sentence = "My name is,    james bond iee. !";
 Map<Character, Set<String>> map = Arrays.stream(sentence.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", " ")
                                                         .split("\\s+"))
                                         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.charAt(0),
                                                  LinkedHashMap::new, 
                                                  Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new)));
 System.out.println(map);
```

Also notice I used the regex \s+ to split the string on any whitspace character.

Output:

```
{M=[My], n=[name], i=[is, iee], j=[james], b=[bond]}
```

Edited to include @davidxxx suggestion in the comments to keep the right order of words along with the letters by changing `Collectors.toSet()` to `Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new)` doing this will also preserve the ordering of words in the set.

Comment: Here you preseve the order of the first letter that appears, not the order of the words  for that letter since you collect with `toSet()` that doesn't guarantee that.

Comment: @davidxxx true! do you think i should re-phrase the answer?

Comment: You could replace `toSet()`by `toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new)` to make it consistent with your initial idea that is good.

Comment: There is no reason to perform two regex operations, like `sentence.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", " ") .split("\\s+")`. Instead of replacing certain matches by a space, just to search for spaces afterwards, just split by the occurrences in the first place: `sentence.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+")` or even shorter `sentence.split("\\W+")`.

Answer (score -1):

```
Stream<String> stream=  myList.stream().filter(name->name.startsWith("v"));
              System.out.println(stream.collect(Collectors.toList()));
```